# Update таблицы через сложный select + сравнение результата. MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

На данный момент мой скрипт Update выглядит так.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[myTable]
SET [isOnlyProgrammerRoles] = CAST (CASE WHEN UserName like '%[^0-9]%' then 0  
else 1 end AS BIT)
```

Теперь нужно обновление сделать по следующему порядку.

1. Cделать селект(перехватил его через entity framework profiler т.к. я такой запрос не написал бы, соответственно в селекте много ненужных символов)

   ```
   SELECT [c.MySiteRole].[Id],
   [c.MySiteRole].[EmployeeId],
   [c.MySiteRole].[RoleId],
   [c.MySiteRole].[SiteId],
   [e.Site].[Id],
   [e.Role].[Id],
   [e.Role].[Name],
   [e.Role].[RoleTypeId]
   FROM   [MySiteRole] AS [c.MySiteRole]
   INNER JOIN [Site] AS [e.Site]
     ON [c.MySiteRole].[SiteId] = [e.Site].[Id]
   INNER JOIN [Role] AS [e.Role]
     ON [c.MySiteRole].[RoleId] = [e.Role].[Id]
   INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP(1) [c1].[Id]
               FROM   [Employee] AS [c1]
               WHERE  [c1].[UserName] = 'testusername'
               ORDER  BY [c1].[Id]) AS [t0]
     ON [c.MySiteRole].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[Id]
   ORDER  BY [t0].[Id],
      [e.Role].[Id]
   ```
2. По результату селекта у меня будет выборка где есть поле `RoleId`. И я должен сравнить каждый `RoleId` с зарание заготовлеными GuidId. Их у меня 5 штук, ну для примера возмем две - FirstGuidId, SecondGuidId.
3. Если в результате селекта все исключительно `RoleId` совпадают с FirstGuidId или SecondGuidId то полю `isOnlyProgrammerRoles` поставить bit 1. Простылми слова названия поля говорит само за себя. Должны быть только роли для програмиста, если по результату селекта будет хотя бы одна другая роль которая не совпадает с нашими FirstGuidId, SecondGuidId, например скрам мастера, то уже полю `isOnlyProgrammerRoles` присвоить bit 0. Как организовать такой Update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если я всё верно понял то вам нужен запрос на update myTable

Можно так

```
UPDATE [dbo].[myTable]
SET [isOnlyProgrammerRoles] = CAST (CASE WHEN Exists (select * from [MySiteRole] AS [c.MySiteRole] 
INNER JOIN [Site] AS [e.Site]
  ON [c.MySiteRole].[SiteId] = [e.Site].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Role] AS [e.Role]
  ON [c.MySiteRole].[RoleId] = [e.Role].[Id]
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP(1) [c1].[Id]
            FROM   [Employee] AS [c1]
            WHERE  [c1].[UserName] = 'testusername' 
            ORDER  BY [c1].[Id]) AS [t0]
  ON [c.MySiteRole].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[Id] Where [c.MySiteRole].[RoleId] not in (ваш список id developers)) then 0  
else 1 end AS BIT)
```

Я предполагаю что программисты всегда есть. И только наличие не только девелоперов вам даст нужный ответ.

Comment: Ну вообще как бы все правильно. Но есть одна неувязочка. Получается что апдейт проходит для всех юзеров в таблице но относительно результата для юзера `testusername`. И тут я в замешательстве, возможно мой селект немного не коректный

Comment: Ну мне решать данных у меня как бы нет. Но ели ответ вам помог то галочка с лева